# Phantomjs stdout error

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, phantomjs

I have the following code:

```
`proc.stdout.on('data',function(data){
 var stringData = data.toString();
 if(stringData.indexOf('\n') === -1)
 temp += stringData;
 else{
 temp += stringData;
 temp = '';
 }
 var result = stringData.split('\n')[1];
 result = JSON.parse(result);
}`
```

I'm getting an error as Unexpected end of input at object.parse(native).

The json being sent from phantom is `{id:temp_id, content:base64}`, the base64 content are all images which are close to 1 MB. My guess is that `stdout.on('data')` is not waiting for the entire data chunks to be received. I tried using stdout on end, but had no luck, the same code used within `proc.on('end)` works.

Comment: Have you printed `result` to see if it is a valid JSON string? Please show what you see.

Comment: The json being sent is system.stdout.writeLine(json.stringify({id:tempid,Content:base64}));

Comment: So, what do you receive?

Comment: {"id":"testid", "content" :"iVxbnnnyetks. The base 64 content is actually incomplete which is got here, there are no closing quotes and also the close of json.